# How do I get compression factor of JPEG image in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, jpeg, nsimage

OSX app reads JPEG images, does some processing and intends to save images with compression factor of original images.

I stumbled with getting compression factor of original images. NSImage class doesn't have nothing similar.

NSBitmapImageRep class has convenient method:

```
- (void)getCompression:(NSTIFFCompression *)compressionfactor:(float *)factor
```

But if I get NSBitmapImageRep from NSData read with dataWithContentsOfFile, I get zero compressionfactor.

Any ideas, how do I get compression factor of JPEG image in Cocoa?

Comment: The compression factor is kind of a loose concept for JPEG. I don't think there's a standard definition, it depends on the software used to encode. It only indirectly affects the values written to the file, so there's no value you can just pluck from the JPEG file.

Comment: P.S. Here's what Microsoft says on the subject for C#: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324790

Comment: Hm, Microsoft's article is quite explanatory. Withal there is way to examine or calculate compression factor of an image. identify utility of ImageMagick suite with key -verbose among others gives compression factor.

Answer (score 1):

With [ImageMagick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php) library it's easy:

```
Image magick_image( [pathname cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] );
size_t compressionFactor = magick_image.quality(); // 0..100
```

It's a mix of Objective-C and C++ known as Objective-C++. Magick++, as name suggests, is C++ library, a wrapper over C-library ImageMagick. In code snippet above Image is C++ class from Magick++ library. pathname is object of NSString Objective-C class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but in my experience it doesn't always work.

```
NSNumber* factor = [imageRep valueForProperty:NSImageCompressionFactor];
```

Here's the Apple documentation of that property from `NSBitmapImageRep`.

**NSImageCompressionFactor**

Identifies an NSNumber object containing the compression factor of the image.

Used only for JPEG files. JPEG compression in TIFF files is not supported, and the factor is ignored. The value is a float between 0.0 and 1.0, with 1.0 resulting in no compression and 0.0 resulting in the maximum compression possible. It’s set when reading in and used when writing out the image.

Available in OS X v10.0 and later.